# Suppression warnings for methods called via reflection

Tags: java

I have java code were the methods are all private and called via reflection. Any IDE i use throws unused method warning. I don't want any warnings in my code. Is there any suppression warnings for the methods that are called via reflection?

Comment: That seems like a serious code smell to me. It could be fine - but I'd recheck my design if I were you.

Comment: How about just disabling the unused methods warning?

Comment: Some options will vary by IDE and whether it is compiler, lint or proprietary warning detection. So it would be helpful to pick one IDE for this question. You can always open a new question if the answer remains specific.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use the [`SuppressWarnings` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void test() {

}
```

also, warnings are reported (not thrown).

Comment: Doesn't it have a more meaning full comment rather than unused?

Answer (score 0):

On a more general note - the methods that you intend to and can use externally directly should not be private in a first place.

private methods are to be used by the class itself only and as such they are most likely not going to be usable by external entities directly.

Comment: While I 100% agree, that does not answer the question. It should be a comment.